# CakePHP: Call to a member function find() on a non-object

Tags: php, cakephp

I get the following errors when viewing my Admin Index

```
Notice (8): Undefined property: ClientsController::$Clients [APP/controllers/clients_controller.php, line 27]

Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /Users/cameron/Sites/crm/app/controllers/clients_controller.php on line 27
```

here is the code:

```
class ClientsController extends AppController
{
    var $name = 'Clients';

    function beforeFilter()
    {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow(array('*'));  
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->set('clients', $this->Clients->find('all'));
    }

    function view ( $id, $slug )
    {
        $article = $this->Clients->read(null, Tiny::reverseTiny($id));

        $this->set(compact('client'));
    }

    function admin_index()
    {
        $this->set('clients', $this->Clients->find('all'));
    }
```

Any ideas what the issue is here? (I have created a Model also)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some potential issues:

Normally

```
var $name = 'Client'; // Not Clients
```

You have a Client, and the controller is for "Clients".

Try:

```
$this->set('clients', $this->Client->find('all'));
```

with the above suggestion on `var $name`.

See a more complete list of potential solutions here if that doesn't lead you down the right path.

[CakePHP call to member function on non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621556/cakephp-call-to-member-function-on-non-object)

Comment: I tried the above mentioned solutions, but it doesnt work. For me the problem is that out of 4 possible cases, only one case shows this error, the remaining 3 cases work properly.

Answer (score 1):

Model names are singular in CakePHP (at least if you follow the naming conventions), which means you have to use: `$this->Client->find('all');`