# Call to a member function find() on a non-object cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CakePHP: Call to a member function find() on a non-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716456/cakephp-call-to-a-member-function-find-on-a-non-object)

I have three Models: Product, Prodpage, Field.

I did the cake console to bake all models based on my local mysql db on my pc.  I then created a simple controller for each model utilizing the public $scaffold.  Here is the ProductsController example:

```
<?php
// app/Controller/ProductsController.php
class ProductsController extends AppController {
  public $scaffold;
}
```

went into my app (localhost/cake/products) and everything worked fine.  I could add products, delete products, edit products.  I could then add prodpages, and I could also add the fields.  I decided to go ahead and use the cake console to bake the controllers and views.  It was my understanding that it should do the same thing as the $scaffold, but this time the controllers should have more of the code in it.  Thus allowing me to start to customize it a bit more.

I go back to localhost/cake/products and it was working fine.  Then when I try to go to localhost/cake/prodpages/add and I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\cake\app\Controller\ProdpagesController.php on line 50
```

Here is the ProdpagesController all they way through line 53(the add function):

```
<?php
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');
/**
 * Prodpages Controller
 *
 * @property Prodpage $Prodpage
 */
class ProdpagesController extends AppController {


/**
 * index method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function index() {
        $this->Prodpage->recursive = 0;
        $this->set('prodpages', $this->paginate());
    }

/**
 * view method
 *
 * @param string $id
 * @return void
 */
    public function view($id = null) {
        $this->Prodpage->id = $id;
        if (!$this->Prodpage->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid prodpage'));
        }
        $this->set('prodpage', $this->Prodpage->read(null, $id));
    }

/**
 * add method
 *
 * @return void
 */
    public function add() {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $this->Prodpage->create();
            if ($this->Prodpage->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The prodpage has been saved'));
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The prodpage could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
        $products = $this->Prodpage->Product->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('products'));
    }
```

and this is line 50,

```
$products = $this->Prodpage->Product->find('list');
```

Anybody know what I am doing wrong here or elaborate on what the error is telling me?  I'm new to cakephp so I am walking through tutorials.  This has me stumped though.

Update: Model/Product.php

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * Product Model
 *
 * @property Prodpages $Prodpages
 */
class Product extends AppModel {
/**
 * Display field
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $displayField = 'product_name';
/**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $validate = array(
        'product_name' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        's7_location' => array(
            'notempty' => array(
                'rule' => array('notempty'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        'created' => array(
            'datetime' => array(
                'rule' => array('datetime'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        'modified' => array(
            'datetime' => array(
                'rule' => array('datetime'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
    );

    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
 * hasMany associations
 *
 * @var array
 */

    public $hasMany = array(
        'Prodpages' => array(
            'className' => 'Prodpages',
            'foreignKey' => 'id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );

}
```

Here is Model/Prodpage.php

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');
/**
 * Prodpage Model
 *
 * @property Products $Products
 * @property Fields $Fields
 */
class Prodpage extends AppModel {
/**
 * Display field
 *
 * @var string
 */
    public $displayField = 'page_name';


/**
 * Validation rules
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $validate = array(
        'is_blank' => array(
            'boolean' => array(
                'rule' => array('boolean'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        'page_order' => array(
            'numeric' => array(
                'rule' => array('numeric'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        's7_page' => array(
            'numeric' => array(
                'rule' => array('numeric'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        'created' => array(
            'datetime' => array(
                'rule' => array('datetime'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
        'modified' => array(
            'datetime' => array(
                'rule' => array('datetime'),
                //'message' => 'Your custom message here',
                //'allowEmpty' => false,
                //'required' => false,
                //'last' => false, // Stop validation after this rule
                //'on' => 'create', // Limit validation to 'create' or 'update' operations
            ),
        ),
    );

    //The Associations below have been created with all possible keys, those that are not needed can be removed

/**
 * belongsTo associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Products' => array(
            'className' => 'Products',
            'foreignKey' => 'products_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );

/**
 * hasMany associations
 *
 * @var array
 */
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Fields' => array(
            'className' => 'Fields',
            'foreignKey' => 'id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );

}
```

I did the cake console to bake these models, so I did the associations within there.  I thought I had Prodpage and Product related correctly.  One product can have many Prodpages.  One Prodpage belongs to one product.

**UPDATE W/ QUERY ERROR**

So when I go to localhost/cake/prodpages/add and fill out the info, selecting a Product from the product dropdown list I get this error

```
Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`builder_cake`.`prodpages`, CONSTRAINT `fk_prodpages_products` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

SQL Query: INSERT INTO `builder_cake`.`prodpages` (`page_name`, `is_blank`, `page_order`, `s7_page`, `modified`, `created`) VALUES ('Page 2', '0', 2, 2, '2012-06-13 16:51:35', '2012-06-13 16:51:35')
```

I looked into to it and it is not passing the product_id associated with the dropdown list selection to add into into the product_id column in my Prodpages table.. any thoughts why?

Comment: It means `$this->Prodpage->Product` doesn't exist, which is probably because Prodpage is not related to Product.

Comment: I edited the post with the Product and Prodpage models. I thought I had them related correctly.. is there something else? or did I do them wrong?

Comment: There's a problem with your model name. You have Product**s** where it should be singular: Product. If your model name is truly Products then use `$this->Prodpage->Products`. Same goes for Fields.

Comment: Thank you!  I looked at it and sure enough it had to do with that.  There is one last question I have. when I try to add a new Prodpage it generates a drop down box to allow me to select the Product it is associated with.  When i select the Product.. it isn't passing that product drop down value in the sql query at all , thus resulting in an error.  i added the info in the main post..

Comment: I added the answer so you can accept it. As for the second question, I think that belongs as a separate question. You'll need to post the HTML form as well. I'm guessing it's an issue with your foreignKey definition being plural again (in the model relationship) but singular in the table.

Comment: thanks for your help!  I will follow up with your suggestion and maybe post a new question if I have too.  Really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem! Hope you figure it out. If not, I watch the #cakephp tag pretty regularly and will maybe see you there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your model names are plural, when they should be singular. For example:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    // Product, not Products
    'Product' => array(
        'className' => 'Product',
        'foreignKey' => 'products_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```